# play series of videos on sharepoint 2013

Tags: video

Can we play a series of videos one after another on SharePoint 2013. And how do I go about it. help please. what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Just create a YouTube channel and create a video playlist, this will make sure that the next clip in the playlist loads when the first one finish. Copy and embed the link to the first clip in SharePoint.

Comment: were not allowed to post in youtube. any other work around?

Comment: There is no OOTB way for having a playlist.  This might help you. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a0b95c38-92c4-4289-b06c-39557cbfccc4/sharepoint-2013-media-with-playlist?forum=sharepointgeneral